# Laravel package to access CiviCRM API3

Tags: api, integration

How do you integrate CiviCRM API3 with Laravel?

I put this question here to link the package I created for this as I wished I would have found more info on the API while searching here.

See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2
down vote
I have published a quick Laravel package that can help building the API3 integration... it also has a lot of documentation that is not easy to find in the Civi world...

Take a look... contribute...

https://github.com/leanwebstart/civi-api3

Also on pakagist... leanwebstart/civi-api3

Hope this helps someone...